# How to edit data attribute value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to…

replace the word yellow with red in data-shown…

then… add the word margin20 to data-shown

then… add the word padding20 to data-shown

then… remove the word tools from data-shown

```js
$(function() {
            var data = $(".testclass").attr('data-shown');
            data = data.replace('yellow', 'red');
            $(".testclass").attr('data-shown', data);

            alert($(".testclass").attr('data-shown'));
        });
    
    //alert should read - w h red margin80 padding20
```

```css
[data-shown~="w"] {width: 100px;}
[data-shown~="h"] {height: 100px;}
[data-shown~="yellow"] {background: yellow;}
[data-shown~="red"] {background: red;}
[data-shown~="margin80"] {margin: 80px;}
[data-shown~="padding20"] {padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-shown="w h yellow tools" class="testclass">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope that what you need

```js
$(function() {
            var data = $(".testclass").attr('data-shown');
            data = data.replace('yellow', 'red');
            $(".testclass").attr('data-shown', data);

            alert($(".testclass").attr('data-shown'));
        });
```

```css
[data-shown~="w"] {width: 100px;}
[data-shown~="h"] {height: 100px;}
[data-shown~="yellow"] {background: yellow;}
[data-shown~="red"] {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-shown="w h yellow" class="testclass">test</div>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to add on one more word with a space…

Comment: like add the word… purple to existing data… with a space?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to understand:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.testclass').addClass('red')  
  alert($('.testclass').attr('class'))//'testclass w h yellow red'
  $('.testclass').removeClass('yellow') 
  alert($('.testclass').attr('class')) //'testclass w h red'
})
```

```css
.w {
  width:100px;
}
.h {
  height:100px;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
.yellow {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='testclass w h yellow'>test</div>
```

Comment: Yes… I understand the addClass… but it needed to be a data-attribute